# Warum heißt es "gut möglich" statt "sehr möglich"?

Tags: word-usage

Warum heißt es "gut möglich" statt "sehr möglich"? Etwa wegen Analogie zu "kann gut sein"?

Ist "sehr möglich" auch geläufig? Immerhin sagt man "sehr wahrscheinlich".

Comment: Idiomatisch ist: gut/ leicht möglich. "sehr"  ist nicht üblich. Habe noch nie darüber nachgedacht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Warum das so ist kann ich nicht beantworten. Ich denke aber, dass das Wort "möglich" nicht gut quantifizierbar ist. Etwas ist entweder möglich, oder eben nicht. Daher passen Intensitätsadverbien nicht.

> sehr, ein bisschen, extrem, wahnsinnig, voll...

Das einzige, was funktioniert, ist

> kaum möglich

Das ist bei Wahrscheinlichkeit anders. Die kann hoch oder niedrig sein.
"Gut" drückt zwar im Endeffekt auch aus, dass es eine hohe Wahrscheinlichkeit gibt, aber streng genommen ist es eher eine qualitative Wertung.

Comment: Das ist sehr interessant, das **möglich** im Deutschen als nicht quantifizierbar angesehen wird. In meiner Muttersprache, im Polnischen, ist es durchaus der Fall: *bardzo możliwy* = sehr möglich, *całkiem możliwy* = ziemlich möglich usw. Deswegen ist Sprachenlernen so nützlich: man lernt viele neue Sichtweisen kennen. +1

Comment: @BarthZalewski... nur zur Sicherheit... ich weiß nicht, ob das wirklich so ist, und wenn, dann ist es wohl eher unterbewusst. Ich denke nicht, das jeder Deutsche das so voll klar auf dem Schirm hat "Oh ja, "möglich" ist nicht quantifizierbar". Es ist nur ein Versuch der Erklärung, warum die Intensitätsworte nicht funktionieren.

Comment: Das ist mir schon klar, dass es unterbewusst erfolgt ^^

Answer (score 2):

Grundsätzlich ist etwas entweder möglich oder nicht. Das Wort [*möglich*](http://www.duden.de/node/643246/revisions/1335763/view) gehört zu den Adjektiven, bei denen laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* die Vergleichsformen im Allgemeinen ungebräuchlich sind:

> Morgen wäre es möglich
> <s>Morgen wäre es möglicher</s>
> <s>Morgen wäre es am möglichsten</s>

(Das verwandte Wort [*möglichst*](http://www.duden.de/node/641057/revisions/1151925/view) ist ein Adverb und kann nicht attributiv verwendet werden.)

An Stelle der Vergleichsformen kann man die Grundstufe *(möglich)* zusammen mit einem vorangestellten steigerungsfähigen Adjektiv verwenden, um den Steigerungsgrad zu kennzeichnen:

> Morgen wäre es leicht möglich
> Morgen wäre es leichter möglich
>
> Morgen wäre es gut möglich
> Morgen wäre es besser möglich